# MVC Upload Object reference not set to instance of an object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Following is the code for **cshtml** page:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("QuotePost", "Quote", null, new AjaxOptions()
{
    UpdateTargetId = "response",
    OnSuccess = "OnSuccessLogin",
    OnFailure = "onFailLogin",
    HttpMethod = "Post"
}, new { id = "frmQuote", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <input name="files" type="file" id="fileupload1" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <input type="submit" id="Upload1" value="Upload" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
}
```

In my **controller:**

```
public JsonResult UploadQuoteByIMEI(HttpPostedFileBase PostedFile)
{
    try
    {
        if (PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(PostedFile.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), fileName);
            PostedFile.SaveAs(path);
        }
        return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
         throw ex;
     }
}
```

In my **JS**

```
$(document).on('click', '#Upload1', function (e) {
    $('#frmQuote').submit();

    $.ajax({
        url: "Quote/UploadQuoteByIMEI",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });
});
```

**Note:** In my controller i have returned null into the json but my concern is that the parameter passed in as **PostedFile of HttpPostedFileBase** is null.

Please help me with this.

**Links i have followed** http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/

Comment: Have a read of this, http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/   it might help.

Comment: @JasonEvans already followed it, does not seems to be working..

Comment: Your input name is `files` so your parameter name should match `HttpPostedFileBase files`. Your script makes no sense. The submit button submits the form (which you don't cancel using `.preventDefault()`) but then you call `.submit()` to submit again and the add some ajax to submit for the 3rd time!

Comment: @StephenMuecke i followed your advice and changed the button type from `submit` to `button` only. And, used the `HttpPostedFileBase files` but still its not working, can you please guide me further.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your doing here. The form action is `QuotePost` but your method is `UploadQuoteByIMEI`? If you use `@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UploadQuoteByIMEI" ...` and keep the `submit` then you don't need the script at all.

Comment: this may help i used to upload via ajax this way:http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2013/08/aspnet-mvc-ajax-file-uploading-using.html

Comment: @StephenMuecke again not working man!!! i dnt know whts wrong with it

Comment: @EhsanSajjad not working need your help further

Comment: you have to use Html.BeginForm file cannot be upload via ajax, have to do hacks using iframe

Comment: @HarshSharma, Is there a reason you cant just do a normal submit with `Html.BeginForm` as Ehsan indicated. Its possible using AJAX using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) but its not supported in older browsers

Comment: @StephenMuecke i do agree to your and `Ehsan` advice, but that what my project lead wants me to do, so i was trying to do it by using `AjaxForm`

Comment: Then you will need to use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects). Some examples [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax) and [here](http://portfolio.planetjon.ca/2014/01/26/submit-file-input-via-ajax-jquery-easy-way/).